# Powershell script only starts first VM in list

Tags: azure, powershell

I have an Azure powershell script to start a list of VMs. When it runs it sucessfully starts the first VM in the list then nothing. No errors are reported, it appears to never return from the start command

**Code as follows:**

```
$vmList = "VM1", "VM2", "VM3"

Write-Output "Starting VMs in '$($AzureResourceGroup)' resource group"; 

Foreach ($vm in $vmList) 
{ 
    Write-Output "Starting VM...$vm" 
    $result = Start-AzureRmVM -Name $vm -ResourceGroupName AzureResourceGroup
    Write-Output "Result of Start VM...$result"
}
```

**When this run it outputs the "Starting VM....VM1", it starts the VM then nothing...**

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your `Start-AzureVM` call is simply *waiting for the VM to finish starting up*.

That is, **`Start-AzureVm` is by default a *blocking, synchronous* operation** - despite its name<sup>[1]</sup>

**To make it *asynchronous*, use the `-AsJob` switch**, which uses a background job to start the VM; the call ends once that job has been created and returns a *job object* that you can use to track start-up progress later, via the usual `*-Job` cmdlets, such as [`Receive-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/receive-job).

---

[1] Regarding the name `Start-AzureVM`:

It is a misnomer in that PowerShell's nomenclature calls for the `Start` verb to exhibit *asynchronous* behavior:

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/cmdlet/approved-verbs-for-windows-powershell-commands (emphasis added):

> **Invoke vs. Start**
>   The `Invoke` verb is used to perform an operation that is generally a synchronous operation, such as running a command. **The `Start` verb is used to begin an operation that is generally an asynchronous operation**, such as starting a process.

Note that the core `Start-Sleep` cmdlet is similarly misnamed.

With synchronous-by-default behavior, there is no good naming solution, because the name `Invoke-AzureVm` would be confusing.

The better approach - which would obviously be a breaking change - would have been to make the cmdlet *asynchronous by default* and offer a `-Wait` switch for to opt-into synchronous operation.